# PHP not processing XSLT / "connection timed out" although local XSLT file

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, xslt

I am using PHP´s built-in functionality to transform a XML-string/dataset I receive from an external source to convert it into HTML.

While this worked fine on my development server, it doesn´t work on the live server (from another company).

I couldn´t find the problem, so they sent me some lines from the error logs:

> [Tue Apr 12 15:29:33 2016] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load(http://mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/xsl/content.xsl) [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 492
>
> [Tue Apr 12 15:29:33 2016] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/xsl/content.xsl" in /var/www/html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 492
>
> [Tue Apr 12 15:29:33 2016] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] PHP Warning:  XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [xsltprocessor.importstylesheet]: compilation error in /var/www/html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 498
>
> [Tue Apr 12 15:29:33 2016] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] PHP Warning:  XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [xsltprocessor.importstylesheet]: xsltParseStylesheetProcess : empty stylesheet in /var/www/html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 498

This looks like the xslt file could not be found but that makes little sense to me, as it´s placed in a local folder, so no reason to drop a "connection timed out"?!?

This is the function which creates the errors, looks pretty fine to me.

```
// Execute XSLT on given string
function xslt_transformation($the_xml_string)
{
    $xml = new DOMDocument;
    $xml->loadXML($the_xml_string);

    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('wp-content/themes/mytheme/xsl/content.xsl');

    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    return $proc->transformToXML($xml);
}
```

**Any hints or ideas what I could look for?**

***Update 1:*** Meanwhile I altered my code, to make sure it looks for a local file for the XSL. This might save a http-call to a file that lies just a subdirectory away. At least I hope so, I don´t know if PHP is smart enough to check that before.

***Update 2:*** I did some testing with the locally loaded XSLT and the whole system seems to run much faster now, at least I got no dubious timeouts this time. I´ll make some more tests with larger XML documents.

Comment: Check the file size, the DOM extension is pretty RAM/process consuming.
You can try to `set_time_limit(0);` so that the script will run longer/forever - however this is not recommended and your web server might impose a timeout.

Comment: Hm, I will have a look into that. Are there any other easy ways to transform XML to HTML with PHP? Or can I make my process less hungry in terms of resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using Wordpress.

Did you tried @Amin.T suggestion?

**OR**

Can you verify the permission for the folder/file?
Refer this URL : https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: Yes, I´m using WordPress. I checked the file/folder permissions, they are fine (755). Setting the time limit to 0 is something I´d like to avoid. But it seems like loading the XSLT locally gave the whole thing a huge speed bost.

Comment: Verify the server settings `allow_url_fopen` set to `true`

Comment: Yes, local and master value are both set to `On`, so that should be fine.